# Computed values on Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I am adding some style to a webpage, and I want to change an object style but when I added the style it has no effect, so I checked the computed styles in the chrome developer tools, but it show that my style is being applied but the result is other.

This is a bug, or I don't understand how computed styles work?

This is what cdt show:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somebody posted a similar problem recently. See [Chrome DevTools: Computed style different from css rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680192/chrome-devtools-computed-style-different-from-css-rule#comment76365754_44680192)

After setting the `border-style` property, `border-*-width` values started rendering as expected.

You can also see that the value for `border-top-left-radius` happens to match the default value set by the `user agent stylesheet`, so my hunch is that you're encountering the same gotcha.

Comment: I tried that but doesn`t work. I get this issue with other values that doesn't match with the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Check inline styling for that element. It should have border radius property.

Comment: If it were that, it should not be displayed on the computed tab? I has not inline style.

Comment: Yes, I mean only border-radious only style. It should be displayed there too.

Comment: border radius is split into 4 components in computed tab.